# HTML table borders not lining up

Tags: html, html-table

I have been tasked with fixing some existing HTML code and I'm hitting a dead-end with my troubleshooting. The main issue lies around some of the borders- they are not lining up no matter how many ways I try to modify the code. On the row with "Job Summary - Other Information" , which is the last row in the table, the border to the right does not line up with the rest of the table.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance! link to fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qnytb58u/4/

```
<tr style='mso-yfti-irow:5;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
<td style='border-top:none;border-left:solid black 1.0pt;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt; border-right:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid black .25pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
<p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Job Summary - Other Information <o:p></o:p></span></span></p>
</td>
<span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
<td style='border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt; border-right:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:solid black .25pt; mso-border-right-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 4pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
<p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'>
<span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>This is the main issue that I can't seem to fix. <o:p></o:p></span></span></p>
</td>
<span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
</tr>
```

Comment: You have different count of columns between _Job Summary_ and _Job Summary - Other Information_

Answer (score 0):

There are some extra td elements in the rows before your "main problem" row. It's pretty tedious work to go through all these - good luck. I've only included in the code snippet your main problematic table, as the rest of the code was too long for the snippet.

```html
<html>

<p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>

<table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="90%" style='width:90.0%;border-collapse:collapse;border:none;mso-border-alt:solid black .75pt;
 mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
    <td style='border:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-alt:solid black .75pt;
  background:#F9F7A7;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><b><span
  style='font-size:11.5pt;mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>You are recieving this email as your Job description for the job <b> 
  HRIS ANALYST SENIOR</b> has been updated effective 09/17/2018. Please review the job description below and acknowledge you 
  have read the job requirements by scrolling to the bottom of this message and clicking the "Acknowledge" button. By clicking 
  "Acknowledge" you agree with the below statement: <br> <br>
  <i>I have reviewed the job requirements. I meet the minimum qualifications, licensure and/or certifications for this role as outlined in the 
  job description. I also verify that I am able to perform all essential functions of the position, and that I may be asked to perform duties 
  that are outside the specific work listed (but not outside my scope of practice).</i> <o:p></o:p></span></b>
        </span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
</table>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></span>
</p>

<table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="90%" style='width:90.0%;border-collapse:collapse;border:none;mso-border-alt:solid black .25pt;
 mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes'>
    <td width=200 style='width:150.0pt;border-top:solid black 1.0pt;border-left:
  solid black 1.0pt;border-bottom:none;border-right:none;mso-border-top-alt:
  solid black .25pt;mso-border-left-alt:solid black .25pt;background:#99EEEE;
  padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><b><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Employee ID<o:p></o:p></span></b>
        </span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border-top:solid black 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:none;
  border-right:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-top-alt:solid black .25pt;
  mso-border-right-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOrig inal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>123450<o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:1'>
    <td width=200 style='width:150.0pt;border:none;border-left:solid black 1.0pt;
  mso-border-left-alt:solid black .25pt;background:#99EEEE;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><b><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Employee Name<o:p></o:p></span></b>
        </span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border:none;border-right:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-right-alt:
  solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>John Smith<o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:2;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
    <td width=200 style='width:150.0pt;border-top:none;border-left:solid black 1.0pt;
  border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;border-right:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid black .25pt;
  mso-border-bottom-alt:solid black .25pt;background:#99EEEE;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><b><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Effective Date<o:p></o:p></span></b>
        </span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;
  border-right:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:solid black .25pt;
  mso-border-right-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>09/17/2018<o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
</table>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></span>
</p>

<table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="90%" style='width:90.0%;border-collapse:collapse;border:none;mso-border-alt:solid black .25pt;
 mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes'>
    <td style='border-top:solid black 1.0pt;border-left:solid black 1.0pt;
  border-bottom:none;border-right:none;mso-border-top-alt:solid black .25pt;
  mso-border-left-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Job<o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border:none;border-top:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-top-alt:solid black .25pt;
  padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>1234 - XYZ<o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border:none;border-top:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-top-alt:solid black .25pt;
  padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span></td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border-top:solid black 1.0pt;border-left:none;border-bottom:none;
  border-right:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-top-alt:solid black .25pt;
  mso-border-right-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span></td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:1'>
    <td style='border:none;border-left:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-left-alt:
  solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Position<o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border:none;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>xyz - IS ANALYST SENIOR<o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border:none;border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:none;
  padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span></td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:none;
  border-right:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-top-alt:none;
  mso-border-right-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span></td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:2'>
    <td style='border:none;border-left:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-left-alt:
  solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>HR Org Unit<o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border:none;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Lalaland<o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border:none;border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:none;
  padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span></td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:none;
  border-right:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-top-alt:none;
  mso-border-right-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span></td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:3'>
    <td style='border:none;border-left:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-left-alt:
  solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>HR Organization <o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border:none;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
    style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Shack<o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border:none;border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:none;
  padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span></td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:none;
  border-right:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-top-alt:none;
  mso-border-right-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span></td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:4'>
    <td style='border:none;border-left:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-left-alt:
  solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Job Summary <o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border:none;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Look at all this text I'm typing. It seems like this job is a lot easier than it looks.<o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border:none;border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:none;
  padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span></td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:none;
  border-right:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-top-alt:none;
  mso-border-right-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span></td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:5;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
    <td style='border-top:none;border-left:solid black 1.0pt;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;
  border-right:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid black .25pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:
  solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span  
    style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>Job Summary - Other Information <o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border:none;border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:none;
  padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'>
  <span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>This is the main issue that I can't seem to fix. <o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td style="border:none;border-top:none;mso-border-top-alt:none;
  padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt"><span style="mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal"></span></td>
    <td style="border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;
  border-right:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:solid black .25pt;
  mso-border-right-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 4pt 3.75pt 3.75pt"><span style="mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal"></span></td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
</table>
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></span>
</p>

<table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="90%" style='width:90.0%;border-collapse:collapse;border:none;mso-border-alt:solid black .25pt;
 mso-yfti-tbllook:1184;mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt'>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes'>
    <td style='border:solid black 1.0pt;border-bottom:none;mso-border-top-alt:
  solid black 10pt;mso-border-left-alt:none;background:#C6C6C6;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt;border-right:solid #c6c6c6 1.0pt;'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><b><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>JOB RESPONSIBILITIES<o:p></o:p></span></b>
        </span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <td style="background:#C6C6C6;border-top:solid black 1.0pt;
  border-right:solid black 1.0pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt;">
      <p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom:0pt"><span style="mso-bookmark:
  _MailOriginal"><span style="mso-fareast-font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;">
  <br style="mso-special-character:line-break">
  <o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:1;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
    <td style='border-top:none;border-left:solid black 1.0pt;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;
  border-right:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid black .25pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:
  solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'> 
 Job Responsibility: - 5884
<br>
Details: Works closely with, and is the primary resource for, the HRIS Manager on HR Metrics and Analytics

 Collaborates with external consultants on various projects

 Will be the back-up system administrator for various HR Information Systems; may be a primary contact with some  vendor(s)

 Participate in various core teams related to analytics and reporting, and systems implementation, training, and configuration

 Coordination and administration of internal surveys (new hire, associate satisfaction, internal customer satisfaction)

 Create and deliver HRIT training initiatives for new or enhanced functionality and maintaining and improving existing technology
<br>
<br>
  <o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;
  border-right:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:solid black .25pt;
  mso-border-right-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:
  _MailOriginal'><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>
  <br style='mso-special-character:line-break'>
  <o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:1;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
    <td style='border-top:none;border-left:solid black 1.0pt;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;
  border-right:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid black .25pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:
  solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'> 
 Job Responsibility: - test
<br>
Details: test
<br>
<br>
  <o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;
  border-right:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:solid black .25pt;
  mso-border-right-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:
  _MailOriginal'><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>
  <br style='mso-special-character:line-break'>
  <o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:1;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
    <td style='border-top:none;border-left:solid black 1.0pt;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;
  border-right:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid black .25pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:
  solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'> 
 Job Responsibility: - Leadership
<br>
Details: Do performance reviews
Compensation reviews
other employee communications
<br>
<br>
  <o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;
  border-right:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:solid black .25pt;
  mso-border-right-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:
  _MailOriginal'><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>
  <br style='mso-special-character:line-break'>
  <o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
  <tr style='mso-yfti-irow:1;mso-yfti-lastrow:yes'>
    <td style='border-top:none;border-left:solid black 1.0pt;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;
  border-right:none;mso-border-left-alt:solid black .25pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:
  solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
  style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'> 
 Job Responsibility: - 0040
<br>
Details: Assess patient’s physical, psychosocial, cultural and spiritual needs through observation, interview, review of medical records & clinical data. Evaluates patient’s response and intervenes to ensure optimal patient outcome. *

Develop and implement patient plan of care and observe outcomes in accordance with nursing standards and in collaboration with the interdisciplinary team. *

Demonstrate competency in a variety of therapeutic/diagnostic interventions including but not limited to IV’s, incision/ wound care, medication administration, catheterization and specimen collections. *

Promote, advocate and collaborate to protect the health and safety and rights of each patient. *

Provide patient/family education through assessment of patient/family learning readiness, needs, and ability. Provide teaching and evaluate effectiveness of teaching. *

Recognize the patient or designee as a full partner in providing compassionate and coordinated care based on respect for the patient’s preferences, values, and needs. *

Provide relationship-based care in which the nurse strives to understand what is most important to the individual and actively engage them in all aspects of care. This care will be delivered with respect for cultural differences and the diversity of human experience. *

Delegates to non-RN personnel in accordance with State Board of Nursing and hospital policy. *

Effectively uses time, personnel, equipment and supplies to provide high quality, cost effective patient care.*

Professional role model for all staff demonstrating ethical/legal/professional nursing process.*

Manages resources and patient flow through matching nursing competencies with individualized patient’s and unit needs.*

Uses standards of care, hospital policies/procedures and regulatory guidelines to guide practice.*

Function effectively within nursing and inter-professional teams, fostering open communication, mutual respect, and shared decision-making to achieve quality patient care.*

Precepts/mentors new staff or nursing students as needed.*

Seeks out learning opportunities and continuing education. *

Seeks experiences that reflect current practice in order to maintain skills and competence in clinical practice or role performance.*

Maintains professional records that provide evidence of competency and life long learning.*

Evaluates one’s own integrity and nursing practice in relation to professional practice standards and guidelines, relevant statutes, rules and regulations. Takes action to achieve goals identified during the evaluation process.*

Demonstrates a commitment to the organization through ongoing participation at hospital and unit based meetings.*

Verbalizes an understanding of the value of measurement and the importance of continuous quality improvement data. Use quality measures to improve performance and accountability for patient outcomes, patient experiences and safe delivery of care.*

Participate in unit-based Quality improvement, evidence-based practice and research activities.*

Use current healthcare research findings and other evidence to expand clinical knowledge, enhance role performance, and increase knowledge of professional issues. *

Adapts to rapidly changing technology as evidenced by competency in technology and equipment used in the patient care setting. *

Thorough and confidential maintenance of patient charts and records. Document ongoing status, interventions, patient response and outcomes in accurate, timely manner. Use information technology to communicate, manage knowledge, mitigate error, and support decision-making. *
<br>
<br>
  <o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
    <td style='border-top:none;border-left:none;border-bottom:solid black 1.0pt;
  border-right:solid black 1.0pt;mso-border-bottom-alt:solid black .25pt;
  mso-border-right-alt:solid black .25pt;padding:3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt 3.75pt'>
      <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:
  _MailOriginal'><span style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'>
  <br style='mso-special-character:line-break'>
  <o:p></o:p></span></span>
      </p>
    </td>
    <span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'></span>
  </tr>
</table>



<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></span>
</p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-bottom:12.0pt'><span style='mso-bookmark:_MailOriginal'><span
style='mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></span>
</p>




</div>

<p>Signature: Joe Smith </p>

<p> Date:

  </body>


</html>
```